# Bokeh show() not opening in default browser

Tags: python-3.x, google-chrome, bokeh, spyder

Till an hour ago, upon running my program which has a Bokeh show(plot) statement, the plot used to show in Chrome which is the default browser. However, the same program and statement are now causing Firefox to open up and half of the time Firefox won't show any plot. I am using Spyder 3.1.4 on MacOS Sierra. I checked inside Chrome settings and it shows that Chrome is the default browser. I also checked on General settings in System Preferences where Chrome is showing as the default browser. Uninstalling Firefox and then running the program causes the plots to show in Safari (where the plots at least show up all the time). Is there a way to get the plots to show on Chrome ?

Answer (score 2):

Bokeh uses the Python standard library `webbrowser` module. If it's opening up something besides Chrome, then that's because Python itself has decided that Chrome is not the default browser (for whatever reason, I can't speculate).

However, if you [refer to the documentation](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/io.html#bokeh.io.show), you can see that `show` accepts a `browser` parameter:

```
show(browser="chrome")
```

which will let you specify any browser you like instead of using whatever the Python default is.

Alternatively, there is an [environment variable you can set](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/dev_guide/env_vars.html#bokeh-browser):

```
BOKEH_BROWSER="chrome" python foo.py
```

Comment: tried using browser="chrome" and browser="google-chrome" but got 'Error: could not locate runnable browser' . After doing a bit of research on this error, attempted to register chrome using webbrowser.register("chrome", None) and was able to execute the command without any error. But still getting the could not locate runnable browser error.

Comment: This is some kind of problem with your python or system configuration. Perhaps Chrome is not on your PATH? I with I had more suggestions to offer, but that's all I know.

Comment: Appreciate your help so far. Will post a solution if and when i find one.

Answer (score 1):

There's a bug with the latest version of MacOS' osascript application which is causing a bug in webbrowser.

You can see chatter about it here:
https://bugs.python.org/issue30392